# How to make a url point to an image file without the extention

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a collection of images in specific folders by category on my website. Each image has an `ID` which is also it's name. The images can be either `PNG`s or `JPG`s.

If a `PNG` image had an `ID` of `abc123` how could the URL be `example.com/category/abc123/` and have the server point to `/images/category/abc123.png` and not `/images/folder/abc123.jpg` and vise versa?

I want to try something with .htaccess RewriteCond & RewriteRule but i'm not positive how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and painless solution is to use `Options +MultiViews`. What it does is simple: if the server gets a requests for a file it can't find, it searches for any files in the same direction with the same name + any file extension (e.g., `foo` would match `foo.jpg` or `foo.png`, but not `foobar.jpg`) and reads that file instead. If more than one match is found, then server "chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document".

[Read more here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: I like this idea, I'll take a look at it and get back with you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
^category/.*/ /images/category/$1.png
```

Try it.

Comment: How would this account for any jpg images?